# Client system details

Tags: php, javascript

Is there anyway of getting client system details like cpu speed, RAM details etc?  Does javasctipt has this capablity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you cannot do this in javascript because of security matters.
What you can get is a system name and version, browser name, screen resolution etc., but not hardware specs.

Comment: And of course getting the browser specifications via JS can be pretty flaky.

Answer (score 3):

No, using javascript that's not possible.

But what you can do is use a [java applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) or even a [flex](http://flex.org) application. For this, the user will have to give you permission to access his computer details, with a simple "Allow" or "Deny" access dialog, raised automatically by java/flex.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The browser has access to that information but unfortunately you do not have access to the browser.